# I got a " 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' " when using loop?

Tags: c#, wpf, html-agility-pack

```
var orth = node2.Descendants("span").ToList().FindAll(x => x.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Contains("orth"));
var type_translation = node2.Descendants("span").ToList().FindAll(x => x.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Contains("cit cit-type-translation"));

if (type_translation != null)
{
    for(int i=0;i<Math.Max(type_translation.Count(),orth.Count());i++)
    {
        if(orth.Count()!=0)
        {
            results.senselist += type_translation[i].InnerText.Trim() +
                                 " " + orth[i].InnerText.Trim() +"\n";
        }
        else
        {
            results.senselist += type_translation[i].InnerText.Trim() + " ";
        }
    }
}
```

App broken up when debugger is playing at `orth[i].InnerText.Trim()`.

EX: orth.count =5 and type_translation.count = 7

As my code: orth[6 or 7] will null and show up error `'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'` at `orth[i]`, type_translation is still having data but I don't know how to check it when it is null? Help me to solve it:

- if "a" is null then return " ";

(= posséder) to have, to have got   ⇒ Elle a 2 enfants. She has 2 children., she has got 2 children   ⇒ Elle a une belle maison. She has a lovely house., She has got a lovely house.   ⇒ Il a les yeux bleus. He has blue eyes., He has got blue eyes.   ⇒ Tu as de beaux cheveux. You have beautiful hair., You have got beautiful hair.   ⇒ Il a beaucoup d'amis. He has a lot of friends., He has got a lot of friends.

I don't have enough point to post photos. sorry.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/647259

Comment: It's nothing to do with *null*, you're trying to access a list past its length. You could check `i < orth.Count()` before you do `orth[i]`.

Comment: You should post your source HTML to your question along with your desired output. I think we can help clean up the code.

Answer (score 0):

You loop condition is asking for the maximum of the count of the two collections - `i<Math.Max(type_translation.Count(),orth.Count())` - so if one is shorter than the other then you're going to have problems.

You either need to use `Math.Min` or perform checks before each time you access the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This is broken:

```
for(int i=0;i<Math.Max(type_translation.Count(),orth.Count());i++)
{
    if(orth.Count()!=0)
    {
        results.senselist += type_translation[i].InnerText.Trim() + " " + orth[i].InnerText.Trim() +"\n";
        // ... 
    }
}
```

Run that through in your head. What happens when `type_translation.Count > orth.Count` and `orth.Count != 0`?  Similarly, what happens when `orth.Count > type_translation.Count` and `orth.Count != 0`?  You have an `IndexOutOfRangeException` because your logic is flawed.

I can't really tell what you are trying to do here, but it is messy.  My suggestion is to figure out what your invariants are.  What is the relationship between the two collections?  Does it make sense for them to be of different sizes?  If so, is it allowed for either to be greater than the other?  Again, if so, then you need to make sure that `i` is smaller than the count of either of them prior to indexing.

This is really a mess right now. I recommend that you maintain your invariants early on so that this logic may be cleaned up.